# how do i prevent this? I really need help on it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

please can anyone help me? 
  I want to know how to prevent user with voting_status='b' or visitor from accessing where user with voting_status='a' can access.

This is Login page where i redirected the user with voting_status='a' and the user with voting_status='b'. 
When you go to your browser and type the page user with voting_status='a' is only allowed to access, it will display even without being Logged in. My question is how do i prevent that? please your answer will be of a great help to me.

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'university portal');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','password007');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
/*
$ID = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/
function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($_POST['UserName']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password, voting_status FROM voters where Username = '$_POST[UserName]' AND Password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!empty($row['Username']) AND !empty($row['Password']) AND $row['voting_status']=='a')
    {

        $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Password'];
        header("location:Result.php");

    }
    elseif(!empty($row['Username']) AND !empty($row['Password']) AND $row['voting_status']=='b')
    {
        $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Password'];
        header("location:Voted User.php");
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}
          ?>
```

This is the Page i want only User with voting_status='a' to access:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Student Welcome</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/bar/bar.css" type="text/css" media= "screen" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type= "text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js" ></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.nivo.slider.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Holder">
    <div id="Header">
        <a href="Home.php"><img src="assets/Logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="NavBar">
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Home.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Login.php">Student Portal</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="Candidate Profile.php">Candidates Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Admin.php">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="About Site.php">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="About Site.php">About Site</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact Us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="Content">
        <div id="PageHeading">
      <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
      <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
      <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
      <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $row_Voters_Account_Form['Fname']; ?> <?php echo $row_Voters_Account_Form['Mname']; ?> <?php echo $row_Voters_Account_Form['Lname']; ?>!</h1>
      </div>
    <div id="ContentLeft">
      <h2>Your Message Here</h2></b>
      <h6>This site is to improve the style of voting in West End University College and other school at large, if it is implementted. </h6>
      <h6>&nbsp;</h6>
      <h6>Note: Please be advice that once you have placed your  vote, you won't be allowed to login again. so there for you can only view the result from of the election from the Hoe page.</h6>
    </div>
    <div id="ContentRight">
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
      </form>
      <table width="400" border="0" align="center">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <img src="slider/IMG-20151117-WA00011234.jpg" name="imageField" data-thumb= "slider/IMG-20151117-WA00011234.jpg" alt="" title="These are the candidates for the election"/>
            <img src="slider/FB_IMG_1484460719710123.jpg" data-thumb="slider/FB_IMG_1484460719710123.jpg" alt ="" title="These are the candidates for the election" />
            <img src="slider/FB_IMG_14845217848411234567.jpg" data-thumb= "slider/FB_IMG_14845217848411234567.jpg" alt="" title="These are the candidates for the election"/>
            <img src="slider/IMAG002012345678.jpg" data-thumb= "slider/IMAG002012345678.jpg" alt="" title="These are the candidates for the election"/>
            <img src="slider/FB_IMG_1484461298331123456.jpg" data-thumb= "slider/FB_IMG_1484461298331123456.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInRight" title="These are the candidates for the election"/>
            <img src="slider/FB_IMG_148446110711012345.jpg" data-thumb="slider/FB_IMG_148446110711012345.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() { 
     $('#slider').nivoSlider({ 
     effect:'random', 
     slices: 15, 
     boxCols: 8, 
     boxRows: 4, 
     animSpeed: 500, 
     pauseTime: 3000,
     startSlide: 0, 
     directionNav:true, 
     controlNav:true, 
     controlNavThumbs:false, 
     pauseOnHover:true, 
     manualAdvance:false, 
     prevText:'Prev', 
     nextText:'Next', 
     randomStart:false, 
     beforeChange:function(){}, 
     afterChange:function(){}, 
     slideshowEnd:function(){}, 
     lastSlide:function(){}, 
     afterLoad:function(){} 
     }); 
     }); 
    </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <table width="0" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Click here to cast your vote" onClick="window.location.href='Voting.php' ">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Footer"></div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Voters_Account_Form);
?>
```

Comment: Your putting the users password as their username in the session vars?

Comment: how does it come now..it works correctly for me

Comment: Do not use `mysql`, It's deprecated (Removed from PHP 7) now. Use `mysqli` instead.

And, don't dare to use GET/POST data directly in sql. use `prepared statement` to make your query injection-proof.

Comment: Please change the question title to something appropriate relating to your problem. Think about how you would search this problem on google.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the empty( ) function to check if values is entered, but my thought is, it would be nice to revalidate all input values with the stored values on database table.

Note: The session for username and password are set when the script is executed the first time. O, subsequent script running see's the session and continues from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not establishing a session variable identifying the user with `a` OR `b`. As well you are not specifying a method for page a or b to determine which user is viewing the page. You need to have both pages check which user is logged in and establish what happens when they do.

When the user logs in you need to set the session like this.

```
$_SESSION['session_voting_status'] = $row['voting_status'];
```

Then with page `a` you should have something like this

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['session_voting_status'] == 'a') {
?>
All your html goes here for user a
<?
} else {
// redirect user to another page
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/user/a");
}
?>
```

Then with page `b` you should have something like this

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['session_voting_status'] == 'b') {
?>
All your html goes here for user a
<?
} else {
// redirect user to another page
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/user/b");
}
?>
```

Comment: yo dont need <? and ?> on every line, just put them at the beginning and end of the code segment

Comment: @NoLiver92 Your edits are incorrect. You have to have closing tags for php in order for the html to render.

Answer (score -1):

Id look at your php at the top of the page, it seems that the sessions will only run if you submit a form. You need to ensure the sessions are enabled all the time in order for the redirect to work if the user logged in then moves to a diffrent page without logging in again.

Id change the function to something along these lines:

```
function SignIn()
{
    if(!empty($_POST['UserName']))   //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password, voting_status FROM voters where Username = '$_POST[UserName]' AND Password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['Username']) AND !empty($row['Password']))
        {
            $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['Username'];
            $_SESSION['Voting Status'] = $row['voting_status'];
        }
    }
}
```

Then outside the function so that the code runs when the page loads you need to include the session start and your header redirection. This will work without needing to submit the form for the code to run. Just remember that the header function needs to be called before any html is sent to the client.

```
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if($_SESSION['Voting Status'] == 'a'){
    header("location:Result.php");
}else{
    header("location:Voted User.php");
}
```

Comment: bro can you still help me, i want to know how to display the name of the user that Logged in from the database

Comment: just echo the session variable <?php echo $_SESSION['Username']; ?> wherever you want it in the html code

Comment: its just echoing the username rather i want it to echo the First name and last name of the user

Comment: @Daniel sorry, you want them seperate. Id recommend returning the first name and last name from the SQL query then put them in session vars. then you echo them as above. You can do it with normal vars but thats only per page, sessions will last while the user is logged in